# getting Authorization Code from Oauth2Login

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm logging to my app using oauth2 with keycloak. How can i get the authorization code that oauth2 should return?
I need it to get the token from an authorization server using following curl:

```
curl -X POST \
https://url/protocol/openid-connect/token \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d 'grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=app_id&authorization_code=<authorization_code>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is sample request to take authorization code

```
GET http://<authorization-server>/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=app_id&redirect_uri=http:%3A%2F%2Fyourapplication.com%2F/login
```

these informations (client_id and redirect_uri) must be registered at authorization server, and authorization code url is generally /oauth/authorize but check your openid providers' url. (in your case, probably /openid-connect/authorize)

after hitting this request, the authorization server redirects you to login page. you enter your credentials, then it redirects you with code to your application which provided by redirect_uri. For example,

```
HTTP 302, http://yourapplication.com/login?code=<your-authorization-code>
```